# Python: Removing entries of one list by duplicates of another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two python lists. In the first list I want to remove all duplicates and in the second list I want to remove the items that are at the places of the duplicates in the first list.

For example from these two lists

```
list_1 = [1,1,2,3]
list_2 = [a,b,c,d]
```

I want to generate these two:

```
result_1 = [1,2,3]
result_2 = [a,c,d]
```

I don't care, whether `result_2=[a,c,d]` or `result_2=[b,c,d]`.

Of course I can think of ways to solve this with simple for loops, but I thought maybe someone can come up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: If you have **working code** but you want some help to make it more efficient/Pythonic, see http://codereview.stackexchange.com. If you have **broken code**, please post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of it along with a clear description of what the problem is. If you have **no code**, please write some.

Comment: Ok, sorry. It's my first question on Stackexchange and I'm not yet familiar with everything. I'll post my code in codereview then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Simple and elegant:

```
>>> list_1 = [1,1,2,3]
>>> list_2 = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> temp = dict(zip(list_1,list_2))
>>> result_1 = temp.keys()
>>> result_2 = temp.values()
>>> result_1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> result_2
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

Since dictionary creates unique keys - you get according values in second list from your `zip()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
list_1, list_2 = zip((list_1[0], list_2[0]), *(item[:2] for item in zip(list_1[1:], list_2[1:], list_1) if item[0] != item[2]))
print list_1
print list_2
```

Output:

```
(0, 1, 3)
('a', 'b', 'd')
```

Whether that's clearer than a simple for loop implementation is another matter.

Comment: this only works if all duplicates are in one sequence, right?

Comment: See my edit, I missed the requirement for the first list.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, actually it is really much simpler with simple for loops. Next time I'll think better before posting a question! Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

def find_duplicates(list_given):
    mycal = Counter(list_given)
    return [k for k in mycal.keys() if mycal[k]> 1]

list_1 = [1,1,2,3]
list_2 = ['a','b','c','d']
list_dup = find_duplicates(list_1)
for x in list_dup:
    if x in list_1:
        list_2.remove(list_2[list_1.index(x)])
print list_2
#['b','c','d']

#For simply removing duplicates from a python list:
# list_with_no_duplicates = list(set(list_with_duplicates))
```